# cpp -v command does not end in terminal

Tags: 20.04, gcc

I use `Ubuntu 20.04`. When I run `cpp -v`in terminal the output is like this:

```
...
...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The problem is after the *End of search list*, the command does not end until I press <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>.

I want to know what causes this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: You've not provided operands, thus it's using *stdin* and waiting for that input.  It'll end when the *end of file* (ie. ^D) is discovered;   It's doing what it should in my opinion.

Comment: @guiverc I did not understand what you mean. Can you tell what you think I have to write?

Comment: View `man cpp` to view the expected & optional parameters in the reference manual. If none are provided the *stdin* (*standard in*), ie. you type in everything you want to provide to the C preprocessor at the keyboard (ie. why it's waiting), and you signal the end-of-file with a ^D as it's been done since the 1970s...  (ie. convention)... Given the *infile*  parameters if you don't want to type the *infile* everytime which is the conventional POSIX *default* (POSIX being the modern term; it was UNIX back in 1970s, 1980s etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man cpp`:

```
   The cpp command expects two file names as arguments, infile and
   outfile.  The preprocessor reads infile together with any other files
   it specifies with #include.  All the output generated by the combined
   input files is written in outfile.

   Either infile or outfile may be -, which as infile means to read from
   standard input and as outfile means to write to standard output.  If
   either file is omitted, it means the same as if - had been specified
   for that file.  You can also use the -o outfile option to specify the
   output file.
```

So, since you are not providing an `infile`, `cpp -v` is waiting for you to supply standard input via the terminal; if you wish to provide *empty* input you can use something like

```
cpp -v /dev/null
```

or

```
: | cpp -v
```